# apigee howto create field and value for all users?

Tags: apigee

I would like to use the appservice console to add a field and value to all users in the users collection.

{
  "isadmin": "1"
}

However when i say "select *" at the query formfield it comes with an error.
"no username was specified"

How can i add the isadmin = 1 value to all users in the usergrid collection?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a value to each member of a collection in one go using the admin console.  It would probably be easiest to do this via a small script via one of the [SDKs](https://developers.apigee.com/get-started).  Alternatively, you can select the users individually and choose to update them one at a time by entering the UUID in the Query field (e.g. /users/) with a body of {"isadmin" : "1"}